# twitter-text library Urls without http:// and with a querystring

Tags: javascript

i'm using twitter-text js library to parse urls . I have a challenge currently i.e the library won't parse urls without http:// and with query string  ex: google.com?utm_source=twitter. The library parses this as just google.com so is there a work around?.

Comment: The question is difficult to answer without seeing your code.

Comment: @Yogi Its general behaviour of twitter library , if go to twitter an try the same you'll see that queryParams are not considered as link when its without http:// or https://.
I was asking if there was a work around for this library behaviour